# TensorFlow: forward pass on pretrained for loss in current model

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, pre-trained-model

I am attempting to use a pretrained FaceNet model implemented in tensorflow found [here](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/train_softmax.py) in order to run a forward pass on outputs of my current model for a new loss on my current model. I do not want to train the weights in the FaceNet model so I will take advantage of `tf.stop_gradient()` at some point.

In order to add a forward pass into my current graph I am importing the entire model structure with `network = importlib.import_module(models.inception_resnet_v1))` more or less following the scheme of training on a pretrained network found in the link. So, within my current model structure I have added something like:

```
network = importlib.import_module("models.inception_resnet_v1")
# set model_dir to where the ckpt file is
self.pretrained_model = os.path.expanduser(self.model_dir)
... previous model structure
```

Then I add my new loss function by looking at the L2 of generated data and real data passed through the facenet inference `network.inference()`:

```
gen_embed = network.inference(...)
real_embed = network.inference(...)
embed_loss = tf.nn.l2-loss(real_embed-gen_embed)
```

Then in training I am calling

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess=tf.Session()

with sess.as_default():
    saver.restore(sess, self.pretrained_model)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

However, I get a lot of output like this

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Data loss: Unable to open table file /data/models/20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

I have only found a way to import trained models and call tensors in a session. I need to add directly to my model structure by using something like `network.inference(data,...)`. I am sure I am missing something obvious, but I could not find any examples like this. I am guessing that my issue is:

1. I am importing the wrong model file 
   or
2. I am not specifying the specific variables in the `network` that need to be restored

Any ideas of how to approach this?

**To Clarify:**

1. I am using version tf 1.0
2. I am using a ckpt file I downloaded

It turns out that I needed to specify the specific variables in the network that needed to be restored.

```
 fn_saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                             scope='InceptionResnetV1'))
```

Saver needs vars specified in order to point the weights to be restored. Otherwise, it was I think by default trying to find all trainable variable weights for the model to be trained, but I only needed to restore a single model.

Comment: (1) To clarify, is it loading a pre-trained checkpoint that's giving this error, or a checkpoint you've written? (2) Which TensorFlow version(s) are involved?

Comment: @AllenLavoie, I made the clarifications. I think I figured it out. I needed to specify which variables needed to be restored otherwise the saver.restore function was not able to find weights for all trainable variables including the main model which is to be trained.